# bash shell script conditional assignment

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I'm writing a bash shell script. There's a required first argument and I want to have an optional second argument.

If the second argument is omitted I want it to use the value of the first argument.

Currently I have:

```
SOMEVAR=${2:-Untitled}
```

How can I use something like `basename $1` instead of `Untitled`?

Comment: PS: You might want to use `${2-Whatever}` (without the ":") to check that `$2` is **undefined** not empty *or* undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do something like `SOMEVAR=${2:-$(basename "$1")}`. You can do any shell or variable in the optional part.

Answer (score 3):

Just use command substitution: `$(basename $1)`, literally instead of `Untitled`.

However, bash also has the ability to do this without an external process: `${1##*/}`

```
SOMEVAR=${2:-${1##*/}}
```

Comment: The problem with using ${1##*/} shell expansion is that it is not an all encompassing replacement for basename. basename does more than just find the last '/' character.

Comment: So `${1##*/}` is equivalent to `$(basename $1)`?

Comment: No, `${1##*/}` isn't equivalent to `$(basename $1)`. For example, if you had `dir=/` and tried `${dir##*/}`, you would get nothing, whereas `$(basename "$dir")` would give you `/`.